# Convert numpy structured array to 2d array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, casting, numpy-ndarray

I have big structured numpy array like this:

```
array([(-0.85694593,  -6.3997216, -1.5486323 , 37, 50,   0,  0),
       (-1.1892447 , -11.417209 , -0.21771915, 97, 50,   0,  0),
       (-0.84541476, -11.3712845, -0.8726147 , 75, 50,   0,  0), ...,
       (-0.057407  ,  -6.266104 ,  1.6693828 , 19,  0,  16, 63),
       ( 0.56391037, -11.262503 ,  0.31594068,  0,  0, 150, 63),
       ( 0.9118347 , -11.4296665, -0.3372402 , 96,  0,   0,  0)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('intensity', 'u1'), ('timestamp', 'u1'), ('m', 'u1'), ('_', 'u1')])
```

Note, that columns 0 to 2 are floats, and columns 3 to 6 are ints.

I want to efficiently convert this array to 2D array of floats. How do I can perform this?

Comment: post how should look the final array

Comment: @mozway, that's different, this structured array has different types and applying just `arr.view((float, len(arr.dtype.names)))` will throw `ValueError: Changing the dtype to a subarray type is only supported if the total itemsize is unchanged`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there was a [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258454/structured-array-of-floats-and-int-to-array-of-floats) for mixed types

Comment: @mozway, the 2nd link works with a slice of columns and does not produce the unified converted set of columns

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, which should be memory efficient at least, and not too slow:

```
result = np.empty((arr.shape[0], len(arr.dtype.fields)), np.float32)
for i, field in enumerate(arr.dtype.fields):
    result[:, i] = arr[field]
```

I assumed you wanted `np.float32` for your resulting array.

Comment: Yes most `recfunctions` use this copy by field approach.  The subpackage also has a `structured_to_unstructured` function, https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured

Answer (score 2):

`recfunctions` has functions to play with recarrays (and by extension structured arrays).  It is documented on the main structured array page.  It requires special loading:

```
In [204]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf

In [205]: arr = np.array([(-0.85694593,  -6.3997216, -1.5486323 , 37, 50,   0,  0),
     ...:        (-1.1892447 , -11.417209 , -0.21771915, 97, 50,   0,  0),
     ...:        (-0.84541476, -11.3712845, -0.8726147 , 75, 50,   0,  0), 
     ...:        (-0.057407  ,  -6.266104 ,  1.6693828 , 19,  0,  16, 63),
     ...:        ( 0.56391037, -11.262503 ,  0.31594068,  0,  0, 150, 63),
     ...:        ( 0.9118347 , -11.4296665, -0.3372402 , 96,  0,   0,  0)],
     ...:       dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('intensity', 'u1'), ('timestamp', 'u1'), ('m', 'u1'), ('_', 'u1')])

In [206]: arr
Out[206]: 
array([(-0.85694593,  -6.3997216, -1.5486323 , 37, 50,   0,  0),
       (-1.1892447 , -11.417209 , -0.21771915, 97, 50,   0,  0),
        ...
       ( 0.9118347 , -11.4296665, -0.3372402 , 96,  0,   0,  0)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('intensity', 'u1'), ('timestamp', 'u1'), ('m', 'u1'), ('_', 'u1')])
```

A relatively recent addition to that library is a pair of converter functions:

```
In [207]: arr1 = rf.structured_to_unstructured(arr)

In [208]: arr1
Out[208]: 
array([[-8.56945932e-01, -6.39972162e+00, -1.54863226e+00,
         3.70000000e+01,  5.00000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-1.18924475e+00, -1.14172087e+01, -2.17719153e-01,
         9.70000000e+01,  5.00000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       ...
       [ 9.11834717e-01, -1.14296665e+01, -3.37240189e-01,
         9.60000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00]], dtype=float32)
```

The `tolist` approach in another answer works because for structured arrays, the result is a list of tuples, which `np.array` can parse just as easily as a list of lists.  The list of tuples, though, is required if you want to make a structured array.  `numpy` developers have chosen display/parse structured array `records` as tuples.

```
In [209]: arr2 = np.array(arr.tolist()
In [211]: arr.tolist()
Out[211]: 
[(-0.8569459319114685, -6.399721622467041, -1.548632264137268, 37, 50, 0, 0),
 (-1.1892447471618652, -11.417208671569824, -0.2177191525697708, 97, 50, 0, 0),
 ... 
 (0.911834716796875, -11.429666519165039, -0.33724018931388855, 96, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Many of the `recfunctions` work by creating a target array, and copying data field by field.  Since usually the number of records is much larger than the number of fields, this is relatively efficient.  I assume `structured_to_unstructured` acts this way, though I haven't examined its code.

I haven't timed these alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In particular a new data type object can be reconstructed with `'names'/'formats'` dictionary, where `'names'` holds the current field names and `'formats'` - the respective dtype format:

```
arr = np.array(arr.astype(np.dtype({'names': arr.dtype.names, 
                                    'formats':['<f4']*len(arr.dtype.names)})).tolist())
```

---

```
array([[-8.56945932e-01, -6.39972162e+00, -1.54863226e+00,
         3.70000000e+01,  5.00000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-1.18924475e+00, -1.14172087e+01, -2.17719153e-01,
         9.70000000e+01,  5.00000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-8.45414758e-01, -1.13712845e+01, -8.72614682e-01,
         7.50000000e+01,  5.00000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-5.74069992e-02, -6.26610422e+00,  1.66938281e+00,
         1.90000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,  1.60000000e+01,
         6.30000000e+01],
       [ 5.63910365e-01, -1.12625027e+01,  3.15940678e-01,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.50000000e+02,
         6.30000000e+01],
       [ 9.11834717e-01, -1.14296665e+01, -3.37240189e-01,
         9.60000000e+01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00]])
```